# KDM Login manager wallpapers

Tags: kubuntu, themes, login, kde, kdm

Just tinkering with KDM and having some trouble with theming. I've downloaded the beatiful zxcity theme and set it as my theme for the KDM login, problem is the wallpaper switches back during load.

Just to simplify that, we have 3 stages to our login.

## Problem

1. Startup machine, goes through the motions,login screen presented with theme.
2. KDE loading screen pops up and goes through the 5 icons (hard-drive, network, KDE symbol, etc..)
3. KDE desktop presented

## Question

I'm trying to get a wallpaper across all 3 of these stages.
To do this I need to:

1. Set my KDM theme (done)
2. ????
3. Set the KDE wallpaper(done)

At stage 2 The wallpaper is reverting back to the default grey stripes thing. Ugly as sin.

Could someone tell me where that image is being called from so I can change it at stage 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Splash**

I think that you are trying to change the KDE splash background.

The Kubuntu 12.04 splashes: Grub "splash" -> Plymouth -> Login Screen (KDM theme) > KDE splash (KSplashX/KSplashQML)

**KSplashX**

The KSplashX REDAME is explaining the splash syntax: https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kde-workspace/repository/revisions/master/entry/ksplash/ksplashx/README

The default KSplash themes are: /usr/share/kde4/apps/ksplash/Themes/.

If you download and install new themes through the "Get New Themes, KDE system Settings > Workspace Appearance > Splash Screen, they are installed to the ~/.kde/share/apps/ksplash/Themes/.

**KSplashQML**

The KSplashQML is a new and shiny:

http://aseigo.blogspot.fi/2011/11/plasma-workspaces-48.html:

> Right now, we do not have documentation on Techbase for this new
>   addition but if one looks in kde-workspace/ksplash/ksplashqml/themes
>   it becomes very apparent.

More: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?56645-KSplashQML-Themes

**Note**

The KDE is caching things to the /var/tmp/kdecache-$USER/. Sometimes the KDE is using the cached picture instead of the changed splash backgrounds. The cached data can be removed: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=45909 .

Comment: Perfect. I had no idea what it was even called but that sounds like what im looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the stage 2 splash:  Applications_menu > System_Settings > Workspace_Appearance > Splash_Screen, there you can change that second stage splash.  Hope this helps someone, I myself was very aggrivated with the same problem until figuring out how to get rid of that drab grey striped thing.